# How to highlight blank cell values in a row that needs data

Tags: excel, excel-formula, conditional-formatting

I'm working on a report that needs to highlight missing cell data in columns D, E, & F if a customer is noted in Column C. I don't want the cells highlighted if there's no customer info in that row.

Below is the code I'm using under Conditional Formatting, but it's not highlighting all the blank cells if there's a customer present in Column C.

```
=AND(NOT(ISBLANK(C2)),D2:F2="")
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CfG7W.jpg)

Worked around with open source references, but due to time limitations I have resorted to requesting assistance here.

Comment: Select the data in `D2:F9` and use `=AND(NOT(ISBLANK($C2)),D2="")`.

Answer (score 0):

The formula

`=NOT(ISBLANK($C6:$C11))*(D6:F11="")`

Applies to:

`=$D$6:$F$11`

[image]